# Unable to use Let's Encrypt cert in Telegram bot webhook (Self-Signed cert works fine)

Tags: nginx, telegram, telegram-bot, lets-encrypt, telegram-webhook

I am trying to setup my **Telegram bot webhook** using a **Let's Encrypt certificate** but Telegram keeps saying *verification_failed*. Browsers, however, are totally fine with new Let's Encrypt certificate.

My self-signed certificate is currently working fine in webhooks on my *Ubuntu 17.04* with *Nginx web server*.

What am i missing?

#### Current self-signed certificate setup (Works)

I generated my certificate using this command:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout my-cert.key -x509 -days 365 -out my-cert.pem -subj "/C=CA/ST=Ontario/L=Toronto/O=My Organization/CN=example.org"
```

and Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    server_name example.org www.example.org localhost;

    listen 443  ssl;
    listen 8080 ssl;
    listen 8443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certificates/my-cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/my-cert.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location ~* ^/bots/mybot/webhook/.+$ {
        proxy_pass          http://0.0.0.0:5000;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

#### New Let's Encrypt setup (Works in browsers, Fails in webhooks)

Certificate is generated for my domain using EFF's great certbot.

When setting Telegram's webhook, I use `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/cert1.pem` file.

This is Nginx configuration I tried:

```
server {
    server_name example.org www.example.org localhost;

    listen  80;
    listen  [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    server_name example.org www.example.org localhost;

    listen 443  ssl;
    listen 8080 ssl;
    listen 8443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location ~* ^/bots/mybot/webhook/.+$ {
        proxy_pass          http://0.0.0.0:5000;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work now? Have you tried my solution jet?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I will get a chance to try it in a few hours.

Comment: How do you solve this ? I have the same problem. I'm using certbot to configure my nginx server. I tried fullchain.pem with webhook, bu t also "cert.pem" (it seems the public cert): from /etc/letsencrypt/live/README: "cert.pem: will break many server configurations, and should not be used". But same result: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Comment: Looking at the answer (and its comment) below, you can see there is no need to pass the certificate when invoking `setwebhook` command on the bot API.

Comment: ok, i didn't understand that solution . I will try, thank u.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this a while ago myself with an Apache webserver but on Ubuntu 17.04 too with letsencrypt and it works fine.

You mentioned that you used the `setwebhook?url=` method with an additional argument (passing the certificate...). Somehow this isn´t needed. You can just enter the url starting with `https://` and you are fine.

Comment: Great. That makes sense because the public key could be obtained during TLS negotiation.